# icon and text in html is not being rendered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html rendering issue, originally i was loading data from mocks and it looks like this.

[image]

When I comment out the code that adds in the mock data my page isn't rendering all the elements correctly

[image]

if i mouse over an element it renders it

[image]

if i add in a blank row

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Task</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="todoListTasksHome"> 
            <tr></tr>                                                                                                                                                    
            <tr id="task_1">
                <td style="width:64px"><button class="btn btn-minier btn-green" onclick="completeTask( 1 )">complete</button></td>
                <td>description</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

it works

[image]

the code looks that adds in the mock data is

```
var load_todo_list_tasks = function () {
    var loadedData = [
    {
        "comment": "",
        "task": "Go see a chiro",
        "task_id": 123,
        "completed": false,
        "completed_date": "",
        "set_date":"07/08/13"
    }];

    if (loadedData.length>0){
        $("#tasks_completed").hide();
        $("#tasks_home_completed").hide();
        numberTasksForToday=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < loadedData.length; i++) {
            var data = loadedData[i];
            numberTasksForToday++;
            displayTodoListTask(data);
        }
    }
};

var displayTodoListTask = function (data) {
    var checked = "";
    if (data['completed'] === false) {
        var completedStyle = "style=\"display:none\"";
        var taskStyle = "";
    } else {
        var completedStyle = "";
        var taskStyle = "style=\"display:none\"";
    }
    if (data['completed_date'] == "") {
        var d = new Date();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        data['completed_date'] = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
        (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        String(d.getFullYear()).substring(2, 4);
    }
    var html =
        "<tr id=\"task_" + data['task_id'] + "\" " + taskStyle + ">" +
            "<td style=\"width:64px\"><button class=\"btn btn-minier btn-green\" onclick=\"completeTask(" + data['task_id'] + ")\">complete</button></td>" +
            "<td>" + data['task'] + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $("#todoListTasks").prepend(html);

    var html =
        "<tr id=\"task_home_" + data['task_id'] + "\" " + taskStyle + ">" +
            "<td style=\"width:64px\"><button class=\"btn btn-minier btn-green\" onclick=\"completeTask(" + data['task_id'] + ")\">complete</button></td>" +
            "<td>" + data['task'] + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $("#todoListTasksHome").prepend(html);

};
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging it as there are no errors in the console log, any ideas?

## Update

```
<li class="active" onclick="showHome()" id="menu_home">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Home </span>
    </a>
</li>
.   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
.   border-bottom-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
.   border-bottom-style: solid;
.   border-bottom-width: 1px;
.   border-image-outset: 0px;
.   border-image-repeat: stretch;
.   border-image-slice: 100%;
.   border-image-source: none;
.   border-image-width: 1;
.   border-left-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
.   border-left-style: none;
.   border-left-width: 0px;
.   border-right-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
.   border-right-style: none;
.   border-right-width: 0px;
.   border-top-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
.   border-top-style: solid;
.   border-top-width: 1px;
.   box-sizing: border-box;
.   color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
.   display: block;
.   font-family: 'Open Sans';
.   font-size: 13px;
.   height: 40px;
.   line-height: 19.5px;
.   list-style-image: none;
.   list-style-position: outside;
.   list-style-type: none;
.   margin-bottom: 0px;
.   margin-left: 0px;
.   margin-right: 0px;
.   margin-top: 0px;
.   padding-bottom: 0px;
.   padding-left: 0px;
.   padding-right: 0px;
.   padding-top: 0px;
.   position: relative;
.   text-align: left;
.   width: 42px;
```

for the home icon

```
.   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
.   background-image: none;
.   background-position: 0% 0%;
.   background-repeat: repeat;
.   box-sizing: border-box;
.   color: rgb(43, 125, 188);
.   cursor: auto;
.   display: inline-block;
.   font-family: FontAwesome;
.   font-size: 18px;
.   font-style: normal;
.   font-weight: normal;
.   height: 36px;
.   line-height: 36px;
.   list-style-image: none;
.   list-style-position: outside;
.   list-style-type: none;
.   margin-right: 2px;
.   margin-top: 0px;
.   min-width: 30px;
.   text-align: center;
.   text-decoration: none solid rgb(43, 125, 188);
.   text-shadow: none;
.   vertical-align: middle;
.   width: 30px;
```

I believe it might have something to do with 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/U5wefygGAow

Comment: Just a side note, you don't need to write `var html` the second time as it's already been declared, you can simply write `html = ...`.

Comment: Can you share a demo?

Comment: Please show us the HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @RobbieJW - agree with you. Ben just initialize your "html" variable once, as you declare it again it overwrite the previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trial and error removed all the javascript and css that wasnt required to reproduce the bug, when I removed

jquery.sparkline.min.js

from the template i have been using it worked.

Answer (score 0):

your code fine there has to be done some thing with the css. try using not to use images as background on the left side. directly use img instead of putting it on background it does create problem. it may solve your problem it solved mine. you should use var html one time only it also creates this type of problems. my answer could be much better if i could see at the html and css.

Comment: i have added the css for an example element